# Enforcing phone number in azure active directory MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have an Azure Active Directory instance where I enabled MFA using Text Messages.

I tried logging-in using a user that has a phone number set in their profile, and was prompted with a dialog containing the user's phone number.

The problem is that this dialog enables the user to edit this number, instead for forcing them to use the one configured in the profile.

How can I make this dialog just use the user's phone number?

EDIT:
This is the configuration in the authentication section:
[image]

Login process: (notice how the phone number can be changed)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research. Firstly, Go to **MFA-> Additional cloud-based MFA settings** set up MFA verification options to use "*Text message to phone*"

[image]

Now, select the users tab and set the MFA to enabled for the user.
[image]

Also avoid MFA from CA policies on the user as it was already set as MFA (mentioned above) to avoid conflict.

You need to configure the users settings to use particular phone number such that it will not prompt users with a dialog saying "*Your organization needs more information to keep your account secure*" to update phone number.

1. Go to **Azure Active Directory > Users > All users.**
2. Choose the user you wish to perform an action on and select **Authentication methods** then add the phone number and save.
   [image]
3. In case we are using alternate phone number then Azure AD will ask us to *enable* to uses default phone number as below image.
   [image]

Comment: I have filled all of these fields, but I am still prompted with "Your organization needs more information to keep your account secure"

Comment: This may be due to SSPR, please test by go into Azure AD > Password Reset > properties > self service password > set it to none. This may avoid the prompt, but will not allow users to reset their own passwords if they get locked out of their accounts. If you're still facing issue then can you please share some screenshots of the message and also more details like when you press next button for the prompt.

Comment: SSRP is already set to None. I've added pictures of the login process to the main post

Comment: Currently, I am not able to reproduce but I will research and update the answer soon.

Comment: Are you using any conditional access on the user?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled conditional access for testing because the UI warned me not to enable it for all of the users in fear of lock-out.

Comment: I have done some research and updating the answer. Hope it helps this time.

Comment: I have disabled the conditional access and enabled "security defaults", but it looks like the user is not prompted for MFA at all now.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Please check my updated answer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214722/discussion-between-gilad-naaman-and-hari-krishna-msft-identity).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using PowerShell (taken from [here](https://jaapwesselius.com/2019/05/09/prepopulate-mobile-phone-for-multi-factor-authentication/))

```
Install-Module -NameMSOnline
Connect-MsolService 
$UserPrincipalName = "j.brown@exchangelabs.nl"
$SMS = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SMS.IsDefault = $true
$SMS.MethodType = "OneWaySMS"
$Phone = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$Phone.IsDefault = $false
$Phone.MethodType = "TwoWayVoiceMobile"
$PrePopulate = @($SMS, $Phone)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -StrongAuthenticationMethods $PrePopulate
```

I am still not sure how to make it the default for all users.