# Setting default for StrongAuthenticationMethods via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm using the following script to enable MFA methods for a user in Azure Active Directory (snippet taken from [this article](https://jaapwesselius.com/2019/05/09/prepopulate-mobile-phone-for-multi-factor-authentication/)):

```
Connect-MsolService 
$UserPrincipalName = "j.brown@exchangelabs.nl"
$SMS = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SMS.IsDefault = $true
$SMS.MethodType = "OneWaySMS"
$Phone = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$Phone.IsDefault = $false
$Phone.MethodType = "TwoWayVoiceMobile"
$PrePopulate = @($SMS, $Phone)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -StrongAuthenticationMethods $PrePopulate
```

It works great, but this means that I'll have to run this anytime a new user is created.

Is there a way I can set it as a default for new users?

Edit:
Here is a previous question that might shed some more light on the issue:

[Enforcing phone number in azure active directory MFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022136/enforcing-phone-number-in-azure-active-directory-mfa)

Comment: Why are you using per user MFA now? The current best practice recommendation is to use a Conditional Access Policy to enforce MFA on your users. There is a tutorial available on the Docs site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa

Comment: One of my requirements is that the user will never be prompted to enter their phone number (as is done usually when setting up the MFA for the first time). This is the only way I managed to do so.

Notice that this code doesn't enable the MFA, but sets the access method.

Comment: Why not just use the Graph then to set those on users? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below snippet at the end,

```
Connect-MsolService 
$UserPrincipalName = "email@email.com"
$SMS = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SMS.IsDefault = $true
$SMS.MethodType = "OneWaySMS"
$Phone = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$Phone.IsDefault = $false
$Phone.MethodType = "TwoWayVoiceMobile"
$PrePopulate = @($SMS, $Phone)
Get-MsolUser -All  | foreach{set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -StrongAuthenticationMethods $PrePopulate}
```